# Resolving some confusion about $\csc x$ and $\sin x$

Tags: trigonometry

I am trying to help my friend solve this.  And it has been more than 14 years since I did this type of math. So I am completely lost.  If anyone can help I would be greatly thankful.

This might be vague but please reference the image.

[image]

Comment: Yes sorry.  It glitch when I posted.

Comment: You may be confusing the following notation: $\sin^{-1}x$ is the inverse of the $\sin x$, while $(\sin x)^{-1}=\csc x$.

Answer (score 0):

You wrote $$\frac{1}{\sin x}=\frac{\text{hyp}}{\text{opp}},$$ and then $$\sin x=\frac{\text{hyp}}{\text{opp}}.$$ If you take the reciprocal of one side, you have to take the reciprocal of both sides: $$\sin x=\frac{\text{opp}}{\text{hyp}}.$$

Comment: Yes thank you sorry about that. Even still, it doesn't work.

Comment: What doesn't work? What are you trying to prove?

Comment: CSC still equals sin-1 , and it shouldn't

Comment: Your algebra shows that $x=\sin^{-1}(\text{opp}/\text{hyp})$, not $\csc(x)=\sin^{-1}(\text{opp}/\text{hyp})$.

Comment: yeah, i know that and that's what i am trying to figure out

Comment: I'm confused about what you are confused with. Aside from the issue I gave in my answer, your math is correct, and in no way suggests that $\csc(x)=\sin^{-1}(x)$.

Answer (score 0):

On the fifth line down, we should see sin x = opp/hyp, not sin x = hyp/opp.

Sin-1 means find the angle given the ratio of the sides instead of the normal sine function giving the ratio of the sides given the angle.
CSC x is just the multiplicative inverse of sine x as in flipping the fraction, not inverting the trig function.

MjB

Comment: Yes, sorry we noted the error on line 5. Sorry, are you able to explain a little further? as in an example?

Comment: CSC still equals sin-1 , and it shouldn't